# Get Conversation live in Nexmo Client

Tags: java, sentiment-analysis, vonage

i am currently working on nexmo voice call project and the scenario is to get live data from the call and transfer the data to `https://www.voicebase.com/` , `VoiceBase` would compute the sentiment score of the conversation . I created the call using the following code below,

```
public class NexmoCall {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JWTAuthMethod auth;

        try {
            JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
            JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) parser.parse(new FileReader("talk.json"));
            System.out.println(new Gson().toJson(jsonArray));
            File fileReader = new File("private_new.pem");
            System.out.println(Paths.get(fileReader.getAbsolutePath()));
            auth = new JWTAuthMethod("secretKey", Paths.get(fileReader.getAbsolutePath()));
            NexmoClient client = new NexmoClient(auth);
            Call call = new Call("+fromno", "tonumber", jsonArray.toString());
            CallEvent event = client.getVoiceClient().createCall(call);
            //VerifyResult request = client.getVerifyClient().verify("+919884474072", "MyApp");
            //CallInfo info = client.getVoiceClient().getCallDetails(event.getUuid());
            DtmfResponse dtmfResponse = client.getVoiceClient().sendDtmf(event.getUuid(), "332393");
            System.out.println("Success! " + dtmfResponse.getMessage());
        } catch (InvalidKeyException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeySpecException | IOException | ParseException
                | NexmoClientException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please clarify your question, what are you having trouble doing?

Comment: Using Nexmo Credentials i am able to make call using client.getVoiceClient().createCall(call); but is there any way to get the conversation data live @SamMachin